Android kotlin move next activity issue
in android kotlin i have 2 activities when i click on backbutton to come first activity before come fisrt activity scree showing me white or blank how to solve it please can you solve it
Thank you
I check every debug but not solved.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

How to override the onBackPressed method in your second activity:
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
        
        // Your initialization code here
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // Perform any necessary cleanup here
        super.onBackPressed()
        // Optionally, you can finish the activity
        finish()
    }
}

If the above steps do not resolve your issue, you can also try disabling the transition animations temporarily to see if that is the cause:
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
}

Additionally, ensure that your first activity's layout is properly defined and that no heavy operations are being performed on the main thread, which might cause a delay in rendering the UI.
